# c openmp - parallelization of a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to parallelize a while loop in C with OpenMP. It is a classic while until flag = false.

This is a semi-pseudo-code of my work without openMP

```
//Something before
found = 0;
while (!found){
  //Pull an element from an array and do some work with it
  if(something) found = 1;
  //Do other work and put an element in the same array
}
//Something later
```

It is not a problem for me if the work in the loop is done some times more, it's just overwork that doesn't affect the results. There is a simple correct way to parallelize this with OpenMP in C?

Thanks

As requested, this is the complete code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>

typedef struct location {int x, y;} location;

typedef struct node {
    int x, y;               // Coordinates of the node on the grid
    int x_prec, y_prec;     // Coordinates of the predecessor
    int walkable;           // Whether this node can be walked through
    int opened;             // It indicates if the node was been estimated
    int closed;             // It indicates if the node was been evaluated
    int inPath;             // If the node is in the shortest path
    int g;                  /* The past-cost function, which is the known distance from the starting
                             * node to the current one. */
    int f;                  /* The estimated-cost function, which is an admissible heuristic estimate
                             * of the distance from the starting node to the goal passing through the
                             * current node. */
    int h;                  // The estimated cost of the path between the current node and the goal
} node;

typedef struct list {
    location loc;
    int isValid;
} list;

location start,end;
node **grid;
int cols, rows;

double time1, time2, time3, time4, time5;
double time_aStar_s, time_aStar_e;
double time_getNeighbor_s, time_getNeighbor_e;
double time_while_s, time_while_e;
double time_for_s, time_for_e;
double time_for = 0;
double time_pull_s, time_pull_e;
double time_pull = 0;
int count_getNeighbor = 0;
int count_current = 0;

void setGrid(char [6]);

int checkLocation(location);

void aStar(int);

int isListEmpty(list *);

void constructPath(location);

void getNeighbor(location, location *);

int heuristic(location, location);

void printStatistics();

void saveStatistics(char *);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    char input_map[20];
    int input_algo = -1;
    char input_stat[20];

    printf("Which map you prefer?\n");
    scanf("%s", input_map);
    setGrid(input_map);
    printf("Enter a valid start point.\n");
    scanf("%i", &start.x);
    scanf("%i", &start.y);
    printf("Enter a valid end point.\n");
    scanf("%i", &end.x);
    scanf("%i", &end.y);
    if (checkLocation(start) || checkLocation(end)) printf("Invalid start and/or end points.\n");
    printf("Dijkstra or A*?(press <0> or <1> respectively)\n");
    scanf("%i", &input_algo);

    // Save when aStar is called
    time_aStar_s = omp_get_wtime();

    if(input_algo == 0) aStar(0);           // 0 for Dijkstra
    else if (input_algo == 1) aStar(1);         // 1 for A*

    // Save when aStar finishes
    time_aStar_e = omp_get_wtime();

    printf("End of the program. \n");
    printStatistics();
    printf("Would you like to save the statistics?(Enter <y> or <n> respectively)\n");
    scanf("%s", input_stat);
    if(input_stat[0] == 'y'){
        printf("Enter file name.\n");
        scanf("%s", input_stat);
        saveStatistics(input_stat);
    }
    return(0);
}

void setGrid(char mapName[6]) {
    char temp[1024];
    char fileName[20];
    int i,j;
    FILE *file;

    // Try to open the file
    strcpy(fileName, "src/maps/");
    strcat(fileName, mapName);
    if((file = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: No such file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Save dimensions of the map
    rows = 0;
    while(42){
        if(fscanf(file, "%s", temp) == EOF){
            printf("EOF\n");
            printf("columns: \t%i \nrows: \t\t%i\n", cols, rows);
            break;
        }
        printf("%s\n", temp);
        cols = strlen(temp);
        rows++;
    }

    // Reset the file position indicator
    rewind(file);

    // Set dimensions of grid matrix
    grid = (node **)malloc(rows * sizeof(node*));
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) grid[i] = (node *)malloc(cols * sizeof(node));

    i=0;
    while(42){
        if(fscanf(file, "%s", temp) == EOF) break;
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            grid[i][j].x = i;
            grid[i][j].y = j;
            grid[i][j].x_prec = -1;
            grid[i][j].y_prec = -1;
            if(temp[j] == '#') {
                grid[i][j].walkable = 0;
            } else if(temp[j] == '-') {
                grid[i][j].walkable = 1;
            }
            grid[i][j].opened = 0;
            grid[i][j].closed = 0;
            grid[i][j].inPath = 0;
            grid[i][j].g = -1;
            grid[i][j].f = -1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void printGrid(int option) {
    int i,j;

    switch(option){
    case 0:
        // It prints grid with start point, end point and optimal path
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if(i == start.x && j == start.y) printf("S");
                else if(i == end.x && j == end.y) printf("E");
                else if (grid[i][j].walkable){
                    if (grid[i][j].inPath) printf("+");
                    else printf(" ");
                } else printf("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        break;
    case 1:
        // It prints evaluated cost g
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j].walkable){
                    if(grid[i][j].closed == 1) printf("%3d ", grid[i][j].g);
                    else printf("    ");
                } else printf("### ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        break;
    case 2:
        // It prints estimated cost g
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j].walkable){
                    if(grid[i][j].closed == 1) printf("%3d ", grid[i][j].g);
                    else printf("    ");
                } else printf("### ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("ERROR: Bad option %i for function printGrid(). Please check the code.\n", option);
        break;
    }
}

int checkLocation(location l) {
    if(grid[l.x][l.y].walkable) return(0);
    else return (1);
}

void aStar(int opt_dijkstra) {

    list openList[10000];
    location current;
    location neighbors[4];
    int empty;
    int found = 0;

    int i,j;    // Counters
    int exit;   // control variable
    int f_min;
    int pos;
    int x,y;
    int ng;

    // Set g and f values of the start node to be 0
    grid[start.x][start.y].g = 0;
    grid[start.x][start.y].f = 0;

    // Initialization of the open list
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(openList)/sizeof(openList[0]); i++) {
        openList[i].isValid = 0;
    }

    // Push the start node into the open list
    grid[start.x][start.y].opened = 1;
    openList[0].loc.x = start.x;
    openList[0].loc.y = start.y;
    openList[0].isValid = 1;

    // Save when the "while is not empty" begins
    time1 = time_while_s = omp_get_wtime();

    // While the open list is not empty
    empty = isListEmpty(openList);

    while (!empty && !found){

        // Save time to pull a node
        time_pull_s = omp_get_wtime();

        // pull the position of the node which has the minimum f value
        f_min = -1;
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(openList, f_min, current, pos, grid)
        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(openList)/sizeof(openList[0]); i++) {
            if (openList[i].isValid == 1 && (f_min == -1 || (grid[openList[i].loc.x][openList[i].loc.y].f < f_min))){
#pragma omp critical(pullopenlist)
                {
                f_min = grid[openList[i].loc.x][openList[i].loc.y].f;
                current.x = openList[i].loc.x;
                current.y = openList[i].loc.y;
                pos = i;
                }
            }
        }
        openList[pos].isValid = 0;
        grid[current.x][current.y].closed = 1;

        //Save time to pull a node
        time_pull_e = omp_get_wtime();
        time_pull += time_pull_e - time_pull_s;

        // Update the count of evaluated points
        count_current++;

        // If the end position is reached, construct the path and return it
        if (current.x == end.x && current.y == end.y){
            printf("Reached the end position.\n");
            constructPath(end);     // To be defined
            found = 1;
        }

        // Save when enter in getNeighbor
        time_getNeighbor_s = omp_get_wtime();

        // Get neighbors
        getNeighbor(current, neighbors);

        // Save when exit from getNeigbor
        time_getNeighbor_e = omp_get_wtime();

        // Get the distance between current node and the neighbor and calculate the next g score
        ng = grid[current.x][current.y].g + 1;

        // Save when started the "for all neighbors"
        time2 = time_for_s = omp_get_wtime();

        // Evaluate neighbors
        /* Seems that is not convenient to parallelize the loop.
         * Probably this happens because of critical section
         */
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(x, y, j) shared(exit, openList, neighbors, ng, grid, opt_dijkstra, end, current)
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            x = neighbors[i].x;
            y = neighbors[i].y;

            if (x != -1 || y != -1){
                // Check if the neighbor has not been inspected yet, or if it
                // can be reached with smaller cost from the current node
                if (!grid[x][y].opened || ng < grid[x][y].g) {
                    grid[x][y].g = ng;
                    if(opt_dijkstra == 0) grid[x][y].h = 0;     // Dijkstra case with heuristic cost = 0;
                    else grid[x][y].h = heuristic(neighbors[i], end);
                    grid[x][y].f = grid[x][y].g + grid[x][y].h;
                    grid[x][y].x_prec = current.x;
                    grid[x][y].y_prec = current.y;
                }

                // If the neighbor is not in open list push it into it
#pragma omp critical (pushopenList)
                {
                    if(!grid[x][y].opened) {
                        exit = 0;
                        for(j = 0; exit == 0; j++) {
                            if(openList[j].isValid == 0) {
                                openList[j].loc.x = x;
                                openList[j].loc.y = y;
                                openList[j].isValid = 1;
                                exit = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    grid[x][y].opened = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // Save when finish the "for all neighbors"
        time_for_e = omp_get_wtime();
        time_for += time_for_e - time_for_s;
    } // End while the open list is not empty until end point is found.

    // Save when finish the "while is not empty"
    time_while_e = omp_get_wtime();
}

int isListEmpty(list l[]){
    // It should check if the list is empty. It checks if there is at least one element that is valid.
    int i;
    int empty = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(l)/sizeof(l[0]); i++){
        if (l[i].isValid){
            empty = 1;
            i = sizeof(l)/sizeof(l[0]);
        }
    }
    return (empty);
}

void constructPath(location n){
    /* The function reconstructs the path starting from the given point setting .inPath
     */
    int i;
    location temp;
    location temp_prec;

    temp.x = grid[n.x][n.y].x;
    temp.y = grid[n.x][n.y].y;
    grid[temp.x][temp.y].inPath = 1;

    for(i = 0; grid[temp.x][temp.y].x_prec != -1; i++) {
        temp_prec.x = grid[temp.x][temp.y].x_prec;
        temp_prec.y = grid[temp.x][temp.y].y_prec;
        temp.x = temp_prec.x;
        temp.y = temp_prec.y;
        grid[temp.x][temp.y].inPath = 1;
    }
}

void getNeighbor(location current, location neighbors[4]){
    /*
     * Get the neighbors of the given node.
     *
     *    offsets
     * +---+---+---+
     * |   | 0 |   |
     * +---+---+---+
     * | 3 |   | 1 |
     * +---+---+---+
     * |   | 2 |   |
     * +---+---+---+
     */
    int i;
    int x = current.x;
    int y = current.y;

    // Update count of getNeighbor executions
    count_getNeighbor++;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        switch(i) {
        // ↑
        case 0:
            if(x >= 0 && y - 1 >= 0 && x < rows && y - 1 < cols && grid[x][y - 1].walkable){
                neighbors[i].x = x;
                neighbors[i].y = y - 1;
            } else{
                neighbors[i].x = -1;
                neighbors[i].y = -1;
            }
            break;
            // →
        case 1:
            if(x + 1 >= 0 && y >= 0 && x + 1 < rows && y < cols && grid[x +1][y].walkable){
                neighbors[i].x = x + 1;
                neighbors[i].y = y;
            } else{
                neighbors[i].x = -1;
                neighbors[i].y = -1;
            }
            break;
            // ↓
        case 2:
            if(x >= 0 && y + 1 >= 0 && x < rows && y + 1 < cols && grid[x][y + 1].walkable) {
                neighbors[i].x = x;
                neighbors[i].y = y + 1;
            } else{
                neighbors[i].x = -1;
                neighbors[i].y = -1;
            }           break;
            // ←
        case 3:
            if(x - 1 >= 0 && y >= 0 && x - 1 < rows && y < cols && grid[x - 1][y].walkable) {
                neighbors[i].x = x - 1;
                neighbors[i].y = y;
            } else{
                neighbors[i].x = -1;
                neighbors[i].y = -1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

int heuristic(location from, location to){
    int h;
    // Manhattan distance from the two points
    h = abs(from.x - to.x) + abs(from.y - to.y);
    return(h);
}

void printStatistics(){
    // Print some useful statistics about the parallel execution of the program
    printf("\nStatistics of aStar:\n");
    printf("time to execute aStar: \t\t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_aStar_e - time_aStar_s));
    printf("time at first check point: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time1 - time_aStar_s));
    printf("time at second check point: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time2 - time_aStar_s));

    printf("\nStatistic of \"while until is empty\":\n");
    printf("number of iterations: \t\t\t\t%i\n", count_current);
    printf("mean time to do an iteration: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_while_e - time_while_s)/count_current);
    printf("time to do all iterations: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_while_e - time_while_s));

    printf("\nStatistic of pull a node into openList:\n");
    printf("mean time to perform a pull operation: \t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*time_pull/count_current);
    printf("total time spent to perform pulls operations: \t%f \tms\n", 1000*time_pull);

    printf("\nStatistic of \"for each neighbor\":\n");
    printf("total number of iterations: \t\t\t%i\n", 4*count_current);
    printf("mean time to do all four iterations: \t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*time_for/count_current);
    printf("time to do the last four iterations: \t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_for_e - time_for_s));
    printf("time to do all the iterations: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*time_for);

    printf("\nStatistic of getNeighbor:\n");
    // time_getNeighbor is updated at each execution, so we have only the value relative to the last execution
    printf("time to execute getNeighbor (last execution): \t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_getNeighbor_e - time_getNeighbor_s));
    printf("number of executions: \t\t\t\t%i\n", count_getNeighbor);
    // Just an indicative time, it is NOT the time to do all executions
    printf("estimated time to do all executions: \t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*count_getNeighbor*(time_getNeighbor_e - time_getNeighbor_s));
}

void saveStatistics(char *string_input){
    FILE *fileOutput;
    char fileOutputName[30];

    strcpy(fileOutputName, "src/stats/");
    strcat(fileOutputName, string_input);
    if((fileOutput = fopen(fileOutputName, "w")) == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Error in opening the output file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    // Print some useful statistics about the parallel execution of the program
    fprintf(fileOutput, "\nStatistics of aStar:\n");
    fprintf(fileOutput, "time to execute aStar: \t\t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_aStar_e - time_aStar_s));
    fprintf(fileOutput, "time at first check point: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time1 - time_aStar_s));
    fprintf(fileOutput, "time at second check point: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time2 - time_aStar_s));

    fprintf(fileOutput, "\nStatistic of \"while until is empty\":\n");
    fprintf(fileOutput, "number of iterations: \t\t\t\t%i\n", count_current);
    fprintf(fileOutput, "mean time to do an iteration: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_while_e - time_while_s)/count_current);
    fprintf(fileOutput, "time to do all iterations: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_while_e - time_while_s));

    fprintf(fileOutput, "\nStatistic of pull a node into openList:\n");
    fprintf(fileOutput, "mean time to perform a pull operation: \t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*time_pull/count_current);
    fprintf(fileOutput, "total time spent to perform pulls operations: \t%f \tms\n", 1000*time_pull);

    fprintf(fileOutput, "\nStatistic of \"for each neighbor\":\n");
    fprintf(fileOutput, "total number of iterations: \t\t\t%i\n", 4*count_current);
    fprintf(fileOutput, "mean time to do all four iterations: \t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*time_for/count_current);
    fprintf(fileOutput, "time to do the last four iterations: \t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_for_e - time_for_s));
    fprintf(fileOutput, "time to do all the iterations: \t\t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*time_for);

    fprintf(fileOutput, "\nStatistic of getNeighbor:\n");
    // time_getNeighbor is updated at each execution, so we have only the value relative to the last execution
    fprintf(fileOutput, "time to execute getNeighbor (last execution): \t%f \tms\n", 1000*(time_getNeighbor_e - time_getNeighbor_s));
    fprintf(fileOutput, "number of executions: \t\t\t\t%i\n", count_getNeighbor);
    // Just an indicative time, it is NOT the time to do all executions
    fprintf(fileOutput, "estimated time to do all executions: \t\t%f \tms\n", 1000*count_getNeighbor*(time_getNeighbor_e - time_getNeighbor_s));

    fclose(fileOutput);

    printf("Saved all the stats");
}
```

If you have suggestion on the other parts of code you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do something like this with OpenMP, but it isn't as simple as putting `#pragma omp parallel` around a for loop.  For that structure, the compiler needs to know at the time of entering the loop how many iterations will be made, so that it can decompose the iterations across threads; and you necessarily don't have that information here when you're exiting once you've found something.

You can make something like this work  - and it can be very useful if the test you need to perform is very CPU heavy (here, I have a made-up example of brute-force primality testing), so that you're breaking up the work amongst several cores, and you only care about finding *a* result (or that there are none).  But note that you are definitely **not** guaranteed that doing this in parallel will return the *first* result.

In the below example, we have a flag `found` that is set (using an [`omp atomic capture`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524509) construct) when a thread finds an item.  If it was the first to set the flag, it stores the value and location.  Once the threads (eventually) see the flag has been set, they all return from the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "omp.h"

/* brute force prime-testing algorithm */
int isprime(int x) {
    int prime = 1;
    for (int i=2; i<=floor(sqrt(1.0*x)); i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            prime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int MAXN=128;
    int start=200;
    if (argc > 1)
        start = atoi(argv[1]);

    int candidates[MAXN];
    for (int i=0; i<MAXN; i++) {
        candidates[i] = start+i;
    }

    int found=0;
    int value=-1;
    int location=-1;
#pragma omp parallel shared(found, candidates, value, location) default(none)
    {
        int tid=omp_get_thread_num();
        int nthreads=omp_get_num_threads();
        int item=tid;

        while (!found && item < MAXN) {
            int prime=isprime(candidates[item]);
            if (prime) {
                int alreadyfound=0;
#pragma omp atomic capture 
                { alreadyfound = found; found++; }
                if (!alreadyfound) {
                    location = item;
                    value = candidates[item];
                }
            }
            item += nthreads;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
        printf("No primes found\n");
    else 
        printf("Found prime: %d (%d) in location %d (%d)\n", value, isprime(value), location, candidates[location]);

    return 0;
}
```

Running gives

```
$ gcc -o stopwhenfound stopwhenfound.c  -std=c99 -lm -fopenmp
$ ./stopwhenfound 370262
Found prime: 370373 (1) in location 111 (370373)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems very helpful. I'll try if I'm able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Jonathan, I think it is very easy to do in OpenMP. You just need to flush the done variable (so its value is consistent across all the caches):

```
//Something before
found = 0;
**#pragma omp flush(done)**
while (!found){
  //Pull an element from an array and do some work with it
  if(something){
     found = 1;
     **#pragma omp flush(done)**
     }
  //Do other work and put an element in the same array
}
//Something later
```